# Django button in html template creates error that I can't solve

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

my code is simple but I admit I have taken it from the internet.
I want to update a model with a button click. Which model, it is chosen by the variable. So I have this html code:

```
<form action="{% url 'reception:update_status' slug=name %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="has arrived">
</form>
```

This code is in url.py

```
re_path('update_status/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$', views.update_status, name='update_status'),
```

and in views.py

```
def update_status(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p = MyModel.objects.filter(name=slug)
        p.status = 'is waiting'
        p.update()
        return redirect(request, 'home')
```

Now with the code like this it comes back with the following error when I click on the button!

```
Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/update_status/Name10'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: POST '/update_status/Name10'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

and I have no clue what this means. Please help?
Thanks

Comment: What is the value of the `name`? Looks like it is a "name" object, not the slug itself. So a first guess would be to replace `slug=name`, with `slug=name.slug`.

Comment: The value of name is "Name10". It is a dummy name for testing purposes!

Answer (score 0):

For regex patterns in Django 2.0, you need to use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path), instead of [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path) for your url.

Comment: That is right, but the error remains. I have updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with pk rather than slugs.

I would recommend everyone who is new to Django to create an id field for every Model. Because that can then be used to pass parameters very easy. Slug is more complicated and makes life unnecessarily difficult!